# Quick regex grep/perl/php

Tags: php, regex, perl

I have this text:

```
2015-03-11 10:15 - anonymous logged in to [127.0.0.1] on account 1DEYKqtPtAEt5hDfiAlz7SdFEGUSPguxGu using key uembzzQdgFHq9k0UJfEi4Dnkvc7n3N5tWVNRQmKfZpeJPnyzKVzKSVVsvLGL6bY 0.2379845 BTC were transferred to address 1cRa5v0Nxu9ABkkzlTv4dzsyRf0hOkg27N using key 1zM9nBd1PNu1FF7qKr1t9Y4m0TawPa3ZQJ1LrlvtViCiB2aFjgn8BIHWG2VHjJvV
```

and I'm trying to extract the pseudo BTC account and the matching key. The text is not regular like the apache logs, so you could have a really long line with 5 or 10 addresses or a single line with the same info. Now how do I match the pseudo BTC account and it's matching key, from the "logged in" and "transferred" part, even if there are a many occurrences in one line?

I have tried this:

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
$string = " ".$string;
$ini = strpos($string,$start);
if ($ini == 0) return "";
$ini += strlen($start);
$len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
return substr($string,$ini,$len);
}
$parsed = get_string_between($fullstring, "account", "using");
```

which gets me the address but not the matching key. I would like to parse the text either using grep, perl or php. whatever works easier. I have been trying with php since I'm at least familiar with the language.

any ideas? I appreciate all your help

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: And please show us more sample inputs, as well. If they vary then a solution to the example in your question would most likely not apply to other inputs.

Comment: @AvinashRaj my expected output would be an address and "key" pair e.g.

    1DEYKqtPtAEt5hDfiAlz7SdFEGUSPguxGu   uembzzQdgFHq9k0UJfEi4Dnkvc7n3N5tWVNRQmKfZpeJPnyzKVzKSVVsvLGL6bY  preferrably in an array (php)

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen

well, the wording doesn't vary, only the length of lines vary. e.g. the above line repeated 5 times on the same line,  but each time with different "btc" address and a "key".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use capturing group based regex in preg_match_all function.

```
$str = "2015-03-11 10:15 - anonymous logged in to [127.0.0.1] on account 1DEYKqtPtAEt5hDfiAlz7SdFEGUSPguxGu using key uembzzQdgFHq9k0UJfEi4Dnkvc7n3N5tWVNRQmKfZpeJPnyzKVzKSVVsvLGL6bY 0.2379845 BTC were transferred to address 1cRa5v0Nxu9ABkkzlTv4dzsyRf0hOkg27N using key 1zM9nBd1PNu1FF7qKr1t9Y4m0TawPa3ZQJ1LrlvtViCiB2aFjgn8BIHWG2VHjJvV";
preg_match_all('~(?:account|address)\s+(\S+)\s+using\s+key\s+(\S+)~m', $str, $match);
print_r($match[1]);
print_r($match[2]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1DEYKqtPtAEt5hDfiAlz7SdFEGUSPguxGu
    [1] => 1cRa5v0Nxu9ABkkzlTv4dzsyRf0hOkg27N
)
Array
(
    [0] => uembzzQdgFHq9k0UJfEi4Dnkvc7n3N5tWVNRQmKfZpeJPnyzKVzKSVVsvLGL6bY
    [1] => 1zM9nBd1PNu1FF7qKr1t9Y4m0TawPa3ZQJ1LrlvtViCiB2aFjgn8BIHWG2VHjJvV
)
```

Comment: works! thanks! That was fast!! 
Question: If the address and key had a fixed length, would that make it easier to parse them? I mean, some keys are invalid (too short or too long) but that is not an issue. 2 out of 100 invalid matches, I can live with that. Thanks, you are a life saver bro!

Comment: [Give some credit to the life-saver.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: marked as answered. Vote Up requires 15 reputation and I don't have that much